# What is the shortcuts to increase the selection range - in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

What are the shortcuts to increase the selection range in Visual Studio (or in any extension).

For example, in html editor, I want to use shortcuts to have the selection grow like,

```
some content > enclosure tag > parent tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this in [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/), a visual studio extension.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>  to increase selection

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>  to decrease selection

It's called **[Expand selection](http://vswebessentials.com/features/html#expand)**